# Search service insdie my SharePoint 2013 , how does it work

Tags: 2013, search, crawling

First of all I have created a new web application inside my SharePoint 2013. Then I defined the following :-

- From managed services I have created a new search service named "MySearch" and I defined the following URL ...://myapplication as the crawl source.
- At First I have defined the crawl setting to perform incremental crawl each 4 hours, then I changed the crawl type to be continuous crawl.

Currently I have the following questions :-

1. I have noted that SP automatically created a new search service named "local Sharepoint sites". So why SP automatically created this service,?
2. and if in the future the two search services (local SP sites and MySearch) contained the same crawl source , will this cause unnecessary and redundant search processing to happen ?
3. Where I should define my application URL as a crawl source? Inside the “Local SharePoint sites” or inside the search service which I have created "MySearch"?
4. As I changed the crawl type from incremental to continues . Currently I have both continues crawl enabled and incremental crawl enabled ? So how I can disable incremental crawl (the incremental crawl button is unchecked but the incremental crawl drop down list still define the interval of 4 hours)?
5. Will defining continuous crawl have some performance drawbacks?
6. And in case I define continuous crawl, is there any reason to define incremental or full crawl settings to take place at any time ?
7. If I define ...//sharepointdev/ as a crawl source. Does it make any difference if I add something such as ...//sharepointdev:4444 or ...//sharepointdev/subsite1 to the crawl source table inside the same search service ?

   Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, automaticly. (Not "service", but "content source")
2. It will prevent you from creating two content source with intersections.
3. Up2u. Choice the most comfortable way for you.
4. To disable crawl choice "No" in the schedule drop down.
5. Continuous crawl work every 15 minutes by default. If you have just one crawl server it will not have any difference from incremental crawl. [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219802.aspx#begin)
6. If you have some complex farm it could be useful to make different crawl schedule for different sources. For example, R&D department may need to crawl data quick and HR department could wait for a hour to data to appear in search results.
7. ...//sharepointdev/  and ...//sharepointdev:4444 are different. All subsite will be checked by rules. So if your rule allow to crawl ...//sharepointdev/subsite1 and you add ...//sharepointdev/ to content source, then ...//sharepointdev/subsite1 will be crawled

Comment: but thing  i have noted, is that in case i select "Enable Continuous Crawls" ,  then the "Incremental Crawl" drop down list will be enabled, so do i have to define the schedule for the continuous crawl , or continuous crawl should not have a schedule ?

Comment: John, you can configure continious schedule. But you can't do it throw WebUI. Only powershell. This topic contains powershell command example and description: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219802.aspx#Proc3

Comment: thanks , Then but what is the purpose of the "Incremental Crawl" drop down, when selecting "Enable Continuous Crawls" check box?

Comment: John, it's interesting. Last time I worked with continuous, where wasn't incremental crawl schedule. I didn't find documentation on it. Hope where will be documentation when I need to work with it. But it's interesting to know. Please let me know if you will find documentation.